# Sketch+PaintCode vs Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, paintcode, sketchapp

[Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/) is a UX and UI design tool. [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/sketch) has a code generating plugin for Sketch that can generate CoreGraphic code for all designs.

For iOS designs that are mostly using the standard design elements like navigation bar, table views and simpler stuff, if we use the code generated by PaintCode plugin, then -

1. Performance: Would there be any any performance impact on the app?
2. Complexity: We will have to take care of navigation and allocating and deallocating views but what is the magnitude of code complexity that would be introduced?
3. What other Pros and Cons are there in using code from PaintCode vs Storyboard?

Comment: this isn't an either-or decision. You can use the generated graphics from paint code with native controls/views in iOS. Trying to make your controls is simply a bad idea unless you have a really really really really good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PaintCode and Storyboards are *not competitive* approaches. In fact, they *complement* each other if you use `IB_DESIGNABLE`.

- **Interface Builder** (for Storyboards or XIBs) allows you build view hierarchy, layout, transitions and relationships.
- **PaintCode** (standalone app or Sketch plugin) allows you to draw contents of the views in a parametric and responsive way.

[image: IB Designable Preview]

<sup>Image taken from this presentation: [IBDesignable x PaintCode](https://speakerdeck.com/86/ibdesignable-x-paintcode)</sup>

Also see PaintCode [video about StyleKits](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/tutorials) and their integration with Interface Builder.
Here you can download an [example project](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/faq/generated-code-compatible-ibdesignable-ibinspectable-designation) that demostrates `IB_DESIGNABLE`.

<sub>— PaintCode Support</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at the videos.